# Why robot and drones were not widely used against Flood outbreak during Forerunners-Flood war

Tags: halo

Just wondering - Forerunners were so advanced race, but they did not widely developed any robots or drones to fight against flood.
Ok, they have drones and sentinels they use to contaminate flood outbreaks on the rings, but why they used actual soldiers to fight flood at first place?
Isn’t it would be better to use robots, as they are protected against flood?